# Starts with not working in while check in Xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have tried different ways but not able to figure out the mistake.I have to do 2 checks to set the value of an attribute.The below example is a simple version of it.

**Input XML**

`

```
<Detail Type="3242432" LastDate="2016-04-22T11:02:43+01:00"
    NodName="10001" 
    UpdateValueReason="Apple: 123 56"
    Date="2016-04-22T11:02:43+01:00">
   <Sub  EventID="2"> 
</Detail>
```

`

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="/Detail/Sub">
      <Status> 
      <xsl:attribute name="StatusType">
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../starts-with(@UpdateValueReason, 'Apple') and @EventID='2'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'23'" />
               </xsl:when>

               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="'1234'" />
               </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:attribute>
      </Status>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I am checking if an attribute starts with certain set of char I am stamping another attribute, but its throwing error

Error while running on cooktop

**Error:**

ERROR: Description: NodeTest expected here.

../-->starts-with<--(@UpdateValueReason, 'Apple') and @EventID='2'

Comment: You should edit your question to say what the error is, as often error messages give useful information. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current syntax would work with XSLT 2.0, but not XSLT 1.0.

Try this instead for XSLT 1.0:

```
 <xsl:when test="starts-with(../@UpdateValueReason, 'Apple') and @EventID='2'">
```